# Echarts accessibility options for the visually impaired

Tags: accessibility, echarts, apache-echarts, color-blindness

Are there ready-made solutions or options for adapting generated/drawn plots (canvas, svg) for visually impaired people in Apache Echarts? I mean, for example, accessibility options for people with color blindness. Options like "invert colors", "high contrast", "greyscale high contrast" or, especially, default styles adapted for people with deuteranopia or protanopia?

Such configuration options or CSS styles that will be applied to the entire plot (chart) or to the entire web page. Without the need to create and apply them manually to individual chart elements.

The only options I found were [`decals` and `aria`](https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/best-practices/aria/).

High contrast themes and a black and white theme are also stated, but in the [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=doc-example%2Faria-decal-newspaper) from the article above, such a theme is created by hand, and is [not offered](https://echarts.apache.org/en/download-theme.html) as a universal ready-made one.